# Deployment issue with GWT app

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, gwt

I have this GWT app which is going wacko when I try to deploy it.

- It's working ok in dev mode.
- It's working ok on my instance of tomcat.
- It's working ok when **alone** on the integration server's tomcat.
- It's crazy when sharing space with another app.

Here is the log:

```
avr. 25, 2014 6:33:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Grave: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract org.xxx.signup.shared.Message org.xxx.signup.client.ValidationService.validatePrefixServer(java.lang.String,org.xxx.signup.shared.MembershipType,boolean)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:127)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:152)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:252)
    at org.red_angus.database.Database.start(Database.java:76)
    at org.xxx.signup.server.ValidationServiceImpl.validatePrefixServer(ValidationServiceImpl.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4jFactory (Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4jFactory)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.createFactory(LogFactory.java:1276)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2.run(LogFactory.java:1065)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.newFactory(LogFactory.java:1062)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:497)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultFileSystem.<init>(DefaultFileSystem.java:44)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.FileSystem.<clinit>(FileSystem.java:114)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4jFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.createFactory(LogFactory.java:1131)
    ... 38 more
```

Any hint would be very useful at this point...

I use:

- `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar` which does not contain `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4jFactory`.

The other app uses:

- `commons-logging-1.0.4.jar`
- `commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar`

which (I think) contains `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4jFactory`, but I am not talking to them!

The other app loads first...

I originally thought of some servlet conflict ([Does two servlets share the same jars on tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279127/does-two-servlets-share-the-same-jars-on-tomcat)) but I made a simple test and they are not "confused".

Comment: `commons-logging.jar` should be in both the app.

Comment: `commons-logging.jar` with no version?

Comment: I am not talking about version.

Comment: Have you checked the common folder for jars?. I do not work with systems but in some way you are using some jar from the other app. Maybe something related with ant or maven?

Comment: Braj: `commons-loggin.jar` is in.

Comment: apanizo: I thought of that too, there is nothing in there that would taken some precedence.